# How to use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation for NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation for NSString, how can i do it? Its working with labels and i need for my function only strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` is used to set the `transform` property of a `UIView`, `NSString` is not a `UIView` so it cant be transformed, it has not concept of rotation

you need to do this at display time with a `UILabel`

an example:

```
NSString *myString = @"whatever";
CGAffineTransform stringTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0f);

UILabel *stringLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
stringLabel.transform = stringTransform;
stringLabel.text = myString;

[self.view addSubview:stringLabel];
```

Comment: display time means the time when you show a string, so when you set the text property of a UILabel

Comment: but i can do something like that: label.center= CGPointMake(x,y)? the problem is giving dynamically x,y.   And where the myString used besides the declaration?

Comment: its a label, you can use it as normal, set the center, font etc. and sorry, missed the .text line

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate text label like below code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    label.text = @"fof fof fof";
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}

- (IBAction)rotate:(id)sender {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(endAnimation)];
    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90.0f * (M_PI / 180.0f));
    label.transform = rotate;

    [UIView commitAnimations];  
}
```